# OpenCV Python Assertion Failed Error imread

Tags: python, opencv

The code opens the image when I reference the file within the same directory as the script.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("art.jpg")
cv2.imshow("original", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I only get the Assertion Failed error whenever I'm attempting to open the same file from one directory deeper.

```
import cv2
import os
import random

dir = 'images'
filename = random.choice(os.listdir("images"))
print(filename)
path = os.path.join(dir, filename)
print(path)

image = cv2.imread("path")
cv2.imshow("original", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

art.jpg

images/art.jpg

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "slideShow.py", line 12, in 
    cv2.imshow("original", image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

Comment: `cv2.imread("path")` There shouldn't be quotes around `path`! Is that your actual code?

Comment: That was it, thanks so much!  I copied the code from other sources - I'm such a newbie I wouldn't be able write all that from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here:

> image = cv2.imread("path")

Your input is a string change it to

> image = cv2.imread(path)

```
import cv2
import os
import random

dir = 'images'
filename = random.choice(os.listdir("images"))
print(filename)
path = os.path.join(dir, filename)
print(path)

image = cv2.imread(path)
cv2.imshow("original", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```